# eclipse window is alway switching

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

Wehn I am coding in eclipse c/c++, eclipse window is always switching and it affects my coding process.
For example, if I am typing a word in A file editor window, then suddenly current window is switched to another window contains B file. 
The second half the word is putting somewhere in the B file, and change the content of B file.
And it always switch from A file to the same place of B file, no matter I am typing in the different place of B file.
Here are the snapshots of A file and B file. In A file, when I am typing in line 155, the window will switch to the line 123 of B file.

[A file Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI8Xl.png)

[B file Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2njg.png)

Comment: Could you share some screenshots?

Comment: The screenshots has been updated.

Comment: Does this occur when you press ENTER key?

Comment: No. It occurs after sometime when I have typing some characters of "CHECK_PORT_NUM".  Does eclipse will switch to the file containing the symbol which I am typing ?